# What is the best way to store secret keys in a production environment?

Tags: node.js, security, config

My application has a lot of secret keys ranging from database authentication password, AWS secret keys, private decryption keys for encrypted data from client etc.. Although it is inside a private repository within the org, I still need to move it from code, to a safer place to limit the keys used on production by any chance from exposure. I am aware of the options of storing them to a config file with limited access, or to export them to environment variables, but see a lot of feedback of downsides of these approaches as well. What is the enterprise standard/ best way to store the keys to limit the access to these keys ?

Comment: This is quite broad and opinion based question. The way to secure your keys greatly depends on variables such as how much money and resources you are ready to put down for it, what is the value of the keys and corresponding threats, does your environment set any limitations or restrictions etc. The most expensive and strongest solutions would include hardware based solutions such as HSMs, TEEs, fuses...

Comment: Most people will tell you just put it in the environment variables unless you work in a large corporate environment or the cia.

Comment: @quinz leaving money aside, we need to even make sure that the performance of the system remains good, and we do not end up with too many encryptions-decryptions cycle. Since data that could be accessed through the keys can be very confidential customer data, we want to make sure the things are right from the beginning, so as not to end up in a mess later even by chance. The data anyway sits on a private network on AWS, but still.

Comment: @thomasmeadows How about the risk of exposing it to other processes running with the same access level as that of my application server or in case of a crash dump?

Comment: Most code is run isolated in docker containers in 2017.  If you deploy to aws, heroku, or digital ocean there are no other processes to worry about.